# Generate summary table from bins of a plot

Tags: r, summary

I have a dataset of the form:

```
d = data.frame(seq(0.01,1,by=0.01), c(seq(0.27,0.1,-0.01),seq(0.1,0.5,0.01),seq(0.5,0.1,-0.01)))
names(d) = c("X","Y")
ggplot(d, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + geom_line()
```

I am trying to generate a summary table that bins the `Y` variable into equal groups of 10% and generate the summary statistics of `X` for each bin. This is how I would like my result to look like:

```
Y Group    X Group
0-10%      {Range1: 10-30%, mean1, median1, sd1} {Range2: 85-100%, mean2, median2, sd2}
10-20%     ... 
20-30%     ...
30-40%     ...
40-50%     ...
```

The ranges of `X` are not always two, 20-30% of `Y` has three ranges of `X` and 40-50% has one.

I have many large datasets on which this has to be implemented. The data is for reproducing the problem. My actual data could have many inflection points, as this code has to run on many combinations of `X` and `Y`.

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Comment: I have written a for loop solution and still struggling with automating the code. On SO for a faster data structure solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output not formatted like yours.

But here is a close solution. You can easily reformat to your liking. It seems you are binning Y in 10 groups but not sure on X. I am using 10 groups on X too.

```
d = data.frame(seq(0.01,1,by=0.01), c(seq(0.27,0.1,-0.01),seq(0.1,0.5,0.01),seq(0.5,0.1,-0.01)))

names(d) = c("X","Y")

library(dplyr)

d$x.decile<-ntile(d$X,10)
d$y.decile<-ntile(d$Y,10)


summary<-data.frame(d%>%group_by(y.decile, x.decile)%>%summarise(mean=mean(X),median=median(X), min=min(X), max=max(X), sd=sd(X)))

> summary
   y.decile x.decile  mean median  min  max          sd
1         1        2 0.175  0.175 0.15 0.20 0.018708287
2         1        3 0.210  0.210 0.21 0.21         NaN
3         1       10 0.990  0.990 0.98 1.00 0.010000000
4         2        2 0.135  0.135 0.13 0.14 0.007071068
5         2        3 0.235  0.235 0.22 0.25 0.012909944
6         2       10 0.955  0.955 0.94 0.97 0.012909944
7         3        1 0.095  0.095 0.09 0.10 0.007071068
```

Comment: Yes, so far I think this should work. Still working on it to test and get the result in my format.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the format you want with `melt` and `dcast` from the `reshape` package.

In the code below, I've cut the data into 10 Y groups and 2 X groups, just to keep the width of the output reasonable. Change 2 to 10 in the `ntile` function to get actual deciles for `X`. Also, I haven't included every summary item, but hopefully the code below will guide you for adding additional information.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

sm = d %>% group_by(`Y decile`=ntile(Y,10), X.decile=ntile(X,2)) %>%
  summarise(`X decile` = paste0("{Count: ", n(), ", Range: ", min(X),"-",max(X),", Median: ",median(X),"}"))

sm %>% melt(id.var=c("Y decile","X.decile")) %>%
  dcast(`Y decile` ~ variable + X.decile, value.var="value", fill="")
```

> ```
>    Y decile                                  X decile_1                                   X decile_2
> 1         1  {Count: 7, Range: 0.15-0.21, Median: 0.18}      {Count: 3, Range: 0.98-1, Median: 0.99}
> 2         2 {Count: 6, Range: 0.13-0.25, Median: 0.225}  {Count: 4, Range: 0.94-0.97, Median: 0.955}
> 3         3  {Count: 7, Range: 0.09-0.28, Median: 0.12}   {Count: 3, Range: 0.91-0.93, Median: 0.92}
> 4         4 {Count: 6, Range: 0.06-0.31, Median: 0.185}   {Count: 4, Range: 0.87-0.9, Median: 0.885}
> 5         5 {Count: 8, Range: 0.02-0.35, Median: 0.185}  {Count: 2, Range: 0.85-0.86, Median: 0.855}
> 6         6  {Count: 5, Range: 0.01-0.39, Median: 0.37}    {Count: 5, Range: 0.8-0.84, Median: 0.82}
> 7         7   {Count: 5, Range: 0.4-0.44, Median: 0.42}   {Count: 5, Range: 0.75-0.79, Median: 0.77}
> 8         8  {Count: 5, Range: 0.45-0.49, Median: 0.47}    {Count: 5, Range: 0.7-0.74, Median: 0.72}
> 9         9     {Count: 1, Range: 0.5-0.5, Median: 0.5}   {Count: 9, Range: 0.51-0.69, Median: 0.65}
> 10       10                                             {Count: 10, Range: 0.55-0.64, Median: 0.595}
> ```

`melt` isn't actually necessary here. You could to the following, where the extra line at the end is to get more explanatory names.

```
sm = d %>% group_by(`Y decile`=ntile(Y,10), X.decile=ntile(X,2)) %>%
  summarise(`X decile` = paste0("{N: ", n(), ", Range: ", min(X),"-",max(X),", Median: ",median(X),"}")) %>% 
  dcast(`Y decile` ~ X.decile, value.var="X decile", fill="", value.name=) %>%
  setNames(., c(names(.)[1], paste0("X decile ", names(.)[-1])))
```

Comment: Thanks for the `reshape` tip!

Answer (score 0):

The `quantile` and `aggregate` functions can help you.

```
# Create data frame
d <- data.frame(seq(0.01,1,by=0.01), c(seq(0.27,0.1,- 0.01),seq(0.1,0.5,0.01),seq(0.5,0.1,-0.01)))
names(d) <- c("X","Y")

# Define bins
bins <- quantile(d$Y, seq(0.1,1,length.out=10))

# Create indicator variable for which bin each Y belongs in
ag <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(d)) {ag[i] <- which(d$Y[i] < bins)[1]}

# Compute summary statistics 
means <- aggregate(d$X, by=list(ag), mean)
medians <- aggregate(d$X, by=list(ag), median)
variances <- aggregate(d$X, by=list(ag), var)

# Put them all into a new data frame
data.frame(group=(1:10),mean=means[,2], median=medians[,2], variance=variances[,2])

##   group      mean median    variance
##1      1 0.4533333  0.200 0.162250000
##2      2 0.4709091  0.240 0.148969091
##3      3 0.3990000  0.265 0.134543333
##4      4 0.4650000  0.305 0.139583333
##5      5 0.3525000  0.325 0.114278571
##6      6 0.4983333  0.385 0.097178788
##7      7 0.5950000  0.595 0.034250000
##8      8 0.5950000  0.595 0.017583333
##9      9 0.5950000  0.595 0.006472222
##10    10 0.5950000  0.595 0.001171429
```